# i want to use im my requirements.txt this tensorflow~=2.3.0 version but i get an error

Tags: tensorflow, version, conflict

This is the requirements.txt

```
numpy~=1.19.2

pandas~=1.2.3

tensorflow~=2.6.0

tqdm~=4.48.2

scikit-learn~=0.23.2

statsmodels~=0.12.2

matplotlib~=3.1.3

scipy~=1.5.2
```

I runned: brew install python@3.8

I got:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python
> version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python
> =3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3

You encountering an error because the version of your tensorflow that you are trying to install is (~=2.3.0) but you python version is not compatible which you have installed.

To resolve this issue,I have two suggestions for you.

Upgrade your Python version to meet the requirements of TensorFlow. Since TensorFlow 2.3.0 is compatible with Python 3.7 and above, updating your Python version to at least 3.7 should resolve the issue. If upgrading Python is not feasible for your work.Then you can change the version of tensorflow that is compatible with your python version.